# Validity of Kirchhoff's current law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Is [Kirchhoff's current law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws) valid for rapidly varying currents such as a one with a frequency in the order of 10KHz?

Comment: There can be slight accumulations of charge during transient events; these adjustments take place at picosecond time scales -- so you would not see them until you get to GHz frequencies.

Comment: For some folks, 10kHz isn't very fast! But, once you account for the effects of a complex impedance, than yes it works. If it didn't, you would have something weird like charge building up somewhere without limit.

Comment: Kirchhoff's laws are always valid as long as your system is closed. At 10kHz it would take some pretty beefy antenna structure to make an electric circuit  "open" in this sense, in which case you would have to consider a more general approach with Maxwell's laws. It does happen, even at lower frequencies, but only for really long conductors or tuned circuits with high Q (quality factor) and it definitely does happen in radio circuits, where we want to have emissions. What's your circuit?

Comment: @CuriousOne mine is just an R-L series circuit. I noticed  that when increasing the frequency of the LFG , voltage across the coil increases and that across resistor decreases in such a way that the sum of their squares remains constant ( in fact it was decreasing very slowly ). However, when frequency becomes in the order of 10kHz , both readings drop to zero.

Comment: The voltage across the inductor and the resistor go to zero in a series R-L circuit? Something is wrong with your signal generator. What are you driving this with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about time constants. Kirchhoff's Laws assume that the steady state has been achieved.

*How do you know if you can make that assumptions in the presence of of time varying driving signals?* By comparing the time scale of the external variation with the time-scale of transients in the circuit.

There are two cases to check first

- **Capacitance and inductance driven time-scale** For a basic RC series circuit (that is one with a resistance $R$ and a capacitance $C$ in series) the time constant is $\tau = RC$ (you should check for yourself that this has units of time, BTW), and if 
  $\tau \, f \ll 1 $
  where $f$ is the frequency of the driving signal, then you can reasonably use Kirchhoff's Laws for this case.
- **Physical extent time-scale** Generally if the circuit is much smaller than $c/f$ than you can ignore the transmission delay around the circuit, but if this is not true you have to worry about propagation delays. People who work on very high frequency circuits have lots of rules of thumb that contradict the ones that are used with ordinary, slowly varying circuits like the one you build on a bench in a first year lab course.

Comment: But what is c/f  ?

Comment: $c$ is the speed of light, and $f$ is (again) the frequency of the driving signal. To be completely accurate we should use the speed $v$ of signal propagation in your circuit, but that is usually in the range of 2/3 to 3/4 of the vacuum value for the kinds of circuits you build in a introductory class so I didn't worry about it. By the time you need to a more precise value you should be able to check for yourself.