# Why can't electrons accumulate at a point in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

The most common reason we get for why the same current flows through all resistors in series is that because electrons cannot accumulate at any point. But why is that? Why can't some free electrons move from their free state to positive ions and similarly why can't new valence electrons join free electrons? Would it not change the current flowing in the circuit? Can someone clarify what I am missing?

Comment: As the band structure of solids is due to quantum mechanics, it would be helpful if you tell us on which educational level you need an answer.

Comment: Actually I am still studying in my class 12th

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kirchoff law of circuit confusing me](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511967/)

Comment: Your instructor may have mentioned [the asummption of steady state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/243240/520) that is part of the "proof" of Kirchoff's laws. My experience is that students often miss it, and then if they start to think hard are confused.

Comment: @Sharad: Could you please clarify in which electric circuit you are interested in. As I read it, you are interested in a series of resistors -- without capacitors. If this is not the case, please state which system(s) this particular question is addressing.

Comment: @dmckee _No_, steady-state is not among the assumptions in the derivation of Kirchhoff's laws. What is assumed is a _quasi-static regime_ (no they are not synonims). For a full derivation, have a look at Fano, Chu and Adler, _Electromagnetic Fields, Energy, and Forces_. As far as I know, this is the only book that presents a complete derivation, which is much more complicated than many people think. There's also a derivation published in the Bell's Lab Journal, but I cannot search it now.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is quite simple: Elecrons repel each other, and they do so quite strongly. The number of electrons is bound to be approximately equal to the number of protons in the solid (out of which only the free electrons can move).

A fun exercise is to calculate the coulomb force resulting from displacement of all electrons in a penny by one meter.

Comment: that penny must be bigger on the inside :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit confusing. Electrons CAN accumulate in a point in a circuit, that's how [capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) charge up.

And the second part of your question concerning free electrons and ions is not very clear.

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Comment: Q: Why can't electrons accumulate at a point in a circuit?
A: They can.

Comment: IF THEY CAN THEN HOW WE CAN OBTAIN A STEADY CURRENT THEN?

Comment: Hmm, the question is about resistors in series. So in my opinion this is not an answer to the question. I agree that the question is not perfectly stated. However, the topic is Kirchhoff's law. So I expect that the questioner is rather young. We should try to answer the question he/she has and just stating that the question is wrong. Do you agree?

Comment: I think the OP is asking about electrons accumulating in a resistor.  Also, I don't believe it is correct to say electrons "accumulate" in a capacitor. Capacitors don't store charge. They store energy.

Comment: If you put a voltage across a capacitors plates, charges accumulate in the capacitor, no? The definition of capacitance is charge (in the capacitor) over voltage, am I missing something?

Comment: @Sharad, steady state implies that all capacitors are charged (so they act as an open switch) and that inductors are also charged (so they act as a closed switch).

Comment: @BobD I see what you mean, electrons accumulate only in half of the capacitor, whatever, they're still acummulating "at a point in the circuit".

Comment: @Sharad, With real wires, there will be some parasitic capacitance between any given wire and whatever other wires are nearby. Because of this some charge will accumulate in the wire. However often (and if we design carefully) this capacitance is small enough that we can ignore it and get a "good enough" model to predict how our circuit will behave.

Comment: @Gyromagnetic OK but just wanted to make sure the OP is not left with the impression that there is change in the amount of charge in the capacitor as a whole. Also that the OP might consider that the “accumulation” of electrons on a capacitor plate as a violation of conservation of charge per KCL. I think it is also important to distinguish between the plate of a capacitor and an electrical node, the latter where we apply KCL and where there is no accumulation of charge.

Comment: I believe a node is defined in electrical engineering as any point on a circuit where the terminals of two or more circuit elements meet. I don’t think the single capacitor plate meets that definition. I raise this distinction because the OP in a previous post questioned the relationship between KCL and conservation of charge. Don’t want the OP to think the accumulation of electrons on the capacitor plate would violate that law since KCL applies to an electrical node.

Answer (score 0):

With real wires, there will be some parasitic capacitance between any given wire and whatever other wires are nearby. Because of this some charge **will** accumulate in the wire (and an equal charge will be repelled from some other conductor, leading to no net charge accumulation in the system as a whole). However often (and if we design carefully) this capacitance is small enough that we can ignore it and get a "good enough" model to predict how our circuit will behave.

In comments you asked,

> IF THEY CAN THEN HOW WE CAN OBTAIN A STEADY CURRENT THEN?

Because once charge has accumulated in the wire, it will oppose further accumulation. We eventually end up with a steady state charge (attributed to the parasitic capacitance) and a steady state current through the wire, which doesn't depend (at all in many cases) on the accumulated charge on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple quantum mechanical ideas involved:

1. Due to the interaction between the charged particles, the solid obtains a band structure. As you already stated some electron occupy states "close to the ion". These electrons are bound to the ions and can not travel freely inside the conductor. In contrast, some electrons form the so called *free electron gas* inside the conductor. They are the charge carriers (i.e. current carrier).
2. The band structure is also due to Pauli's exclusion principle (which is a symmetry principle and not an interaction). Pauli's principle states that two electrons can't occupy the same state (simplified version). Thus, if a bound state ("near an ion") is occupied, no electron from the free electron gas is allowed to occupy this state. The state is filled.

Now the idea of a solid is to fill up the allowed electron states starting with the states which posses the lowest energy. These are the bound states (they are "closer" to  the positively charged ions). If the solid possesses only "few" electrons, such that all of them find a bound state, then we call the solid a non-conductor. In contrast, if the solid possesses "many" electrons then some of the electrons must occupy free electron states and we call the solid a conductor (I won't go into semi-conductors, here) -- note that I define "few" and "many" with respect to the available number of bound states.

I believe that the simplest picture is that the "bounded electrons" shield the ions from the "free electrons". Just as every single atom can occupy only a certain amount of electrons before it is electrical neutral, this is also true for a solid. However, since two ions can share a "bounded electron", they don't need all their electrons to compensate their electrically positiv charge.